# How to pass a newly add item from a jcombo box to mysql database

Tags: java, mysql, jcombobox

I have a jcombobox that populates data from a mysql table.  I add a new item to the jcombobox and want to add that item back to the mysql table.  I can successful add the item to the jcombobox list, but when I try to add the selected item to the mysql table, it adds a null value.

What am I doing wrong?  Here is my code...

```
checkitems = con.createStatement();
ResultSet rs = checkitems.executeQuery("SELECT * from artist WHERE artist = '" +(String)art_combo.getSelectedItem()+ "'");
        System.out.println((String)art_combo.getSelectedItem());
        while (rs.next()){
            String artist = rs.getString("artist");
            System.out.println("The value of variable artist is "+artist);

            String art = (String)art_combo.getSelectedItem();
            System.out.println("The value at art variable is "+art+" and the value at artist variable is "+artist+" .");
            System.out.println("The value of variable art is "+art);


            if (artist.equals(art)){
                System.out.println("Artist already exist.  Nothing added!!!");
            }else{
                stm1 = con.prepareStatement("INSERT into artist"+"(artist)"+"VALUES ('?')");
                try{
                    stm1.setString(1, art);
                    System.out.println(art);
                    stm1.executeUpdate();
                }
                catch (SQLException e){
                System.out.print(e);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: The logic in the code is fundamentally wrong. You need to make a record in the database when you add an item to the control.

Comment: I have an actionlistener attached to combobox that detects whether or not an item was typed or selected.  If typed, it adds the item to the combo box list.